# r shiny-Add valueBox on the navlistPanel Page

Tags: r, shiny

I want to add a valueBox() in the shiny app on navlistPanel page but it does not work. The ui.R code is as below:

```
 library(shiny)
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
    navlistPanel(
         valueBox(10 * 2, "Numder of Project", icon = icon("credit-card"))  
         )
 ))
```

I am wondering if valuebox only can be used in shinyDashboard structure, or 
is there some solutions can allowed me to use it on navlistPanel page, thanks.

Comment: `valueBox` doesn't exist in `shiny`. It's only in `shinydashboard`.